# Application not listed in Android Auto

Tags: android, android-auto

I'm trying to develop a media application for Android Auto. To help me, I've downloaded the AndroidMediaBrowserService Sample (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-MediaBrowserService).
I've succeded in installing the application, but when I launch Android Auto on my phone and I click the Media icon in the bottom right corner, the application is not listed with the other ones and I can't find out why. Can someone help me please ?

Comment: This could be because of android auto not being in developer mode. To activate dev mode in android auto start it on the phone without it being connected to anything and then go to the old start screen of the app ( it should be information ) then tap on the text "About android auto" at the top repeadetly until you get the message you are now in developer mode. Then you will have dev options available if you click on the three dots at the top right. In there is a tick for not signed apps (or something like that) , maybe this has to be checked to gain access to your custom app for android auto.

Comment: The developer mode is activated in Android Auto application and on the phone to install the apk from Android Studio

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to test the application in **Physical Android Auto device**
(Real Head Unit), note that the car application will not show up unless you **install the app from Google Playstore** as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/apps/auto#car-head-unit).

So for development purposes use the Desktop Head Unit (DHU) Emulator.

Answer (score 2):

enable developer mode in android auto emulator as well, so that it can identify your debug version of phone apk. 
https://www.howtogeek.com/271132/how-to-enable-developer-settings-on-android-auto/

put application mode as developer.

Comment: The developer mode is enabled and "developer" application mode is set. I have even checked "Unknown Sources". Still it won't word.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see that in manifest file:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.car.application"
        android:resource="@xml/automotive_app_desc"/>

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.car.notification.SmallIcon"
        android:resource="@drawable/ic_notification" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearing app data for Android Auto worked for me.
Developer mode and unknown sources need to be on in Android Auto of course.